# How can I rerun a statement from server logs without manual editing?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have some statements in my logs like this:

```
SELECT to_char("version_downloads"."date", $1), SUM(version_downloads.downloads) FROM "version_downloads" WHERE "version_downloads"."version_id" IN ($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57) GROUP BY "version_downloads"."date" ORDER BY "version_downloads"."date" ASC
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'YYYY-MM-DD', $2 = '154971', $3 = '130460', $4 = '127212', $5 = '125555', $6 = '125521', $7 = '119212', $8 = '117808', $9 = '115893', $10 = '113343', $11 = '130165', $12 = '102932', $13 = '99538', $14 = '98022', $15 = '97193', $16 = '95831', $17 = '93664', $18 = '92908', $19 = '89893', $20 = '86584', $21 = '130166', $22 = '127355', $23 = '127151', $24 = '104133', $25 = '76564', $26 = '74803', $27 = '73853', $28 = '130167', $29 = '79903', $30 = '78200', $31 = '76563', $32 = '75606', $33 = '70485', $34 = '67607', $35 = '60891', $36 = '38564', $37 = '22300', $38 = '20439', $39 = '17884', $40 = '15268', $41 = '14687', $42 = '13851', $43 = '9238', $44 = '7843', $45 = '7771', $46 = '7710', $47 = '7648', $48 = '7248', $49 = '7239', $50 = '7237', $51 = '6964', $52 = '6704', $53 = '6029', $54 = '5937', $55 = '5252', $56 = '4371', $57 = '4362'
```

These statements were generated by an ORM. I would like to rerun this query in `psql` so I can optionally do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and change parts of the query and so forth. Ideally, I would like to be able to copy queries like this one and paste it into `psql` without any modification. Small modifications are acceptable, like copying only parts or adding text to the beginning or the end.

When I try copy-pasting directly, the `SELECT` isn't valid:

```
# SELECT to_char("version_downloads"."date", $1), SUM(version_downloads.downloads) FROM "version_downloads" WHERE "version_downloads"."version_id" IN ($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57) GROUP BY "version_downloads"."date" ORDER BY "version_downloads"."date" ASC;
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 1: SELECT to_char("version_downloads"."date", $1), SUM(version_...
```

Trying to run this as a prepared statement by adding `PREPARE [name] AS` to the beginning of the select and `execute foo()` around the parameters also doesn't work:

```
# PREPARE foo AS SELECT to_char("version_downloads"."date", $1), SUM(version_downloads.downloads) FROM "version_downloads" WHERE "version_downloads"."version_id" IN ($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57) GROUP BY "version_downloads"."date" ORDER BY "version_downloads"."date" ASC;
PREPARE

# execute foo($1 = 'YYYY-MM-DD', $2 = '154971', $3 = '130460', $4 = '127212', $5 = '125555', $6 = '125521', $7 = '119212', $8 = '117808', $9 = '115893', $10 = '113343', $11 = '130165', $12 = '102932', $13 = '99538', $14 = '98022', $15 = '97193', $16 = '95831', $17 = '93664', $18 = '92908', $19 = '89893', $20 = '86584', $21 = '130166', $22 = '127355', $23 = '127151', $24 = '104133', $25 = '76564', $26 = '74803', $27 = '73853', $28 = '130167', $29 = '79903', $30 = '78200', $31 = '76563', $32 = '75606', $33 = '70485', $34 = '67607', $35 = '60891', $36 = '38564', $37 = '22300', $38 = '20439', $39 = '17884', $40 = '15268', $41 = '14687', $42 = '13851', $43 = '9238', $44 = '7843', $45 = '7771', $46 = '7710', $47 = '7648', $48 = '7248', $49 = '7239', $50 = '7237', $51 = '6964', $52 = '6704', $53 = '6029', $54 = '5937', $55 = '5252', $56 = '4371', $57 = '4362');
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 1: execute foo($1 = 'YYYY-MM-DD', $2 = '154971', $3 = '130460',...
                    ^
```

Is there a setting I can change for the log format so that the queries are copy-pasteable? Is there an alternate way of calling the prepared statement? Do I need to write a script to turn the logs into a well-formatted query?

Comment: Use: `execute foo('YYYY-MM-DD', '154971', '130460',...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [pgreplay](https://github.com/laurenz/pgreplay) to replay statements from the log, but then that's not surprising, since I wrote that tool.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as accepted-- I might have some pull requests for you, but at least you have the log parsing part working so I don't have to do that ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
test=# prepare test as select to_char(current_date,$1);
LOG:  statement: prepare test as select to_char(current_date,$1);
LOG:  duration: 0.089 ms
PREPARE
test=# execute test($1='YYYY-MM-DD');
LOG:  statement: execute test($1='YYYY-MM-DD');
DETAIL:  prepare: prepare test as select to_char(current_date,$1);
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 1: execute test($1='YYYY-MM-DD');
                     ^
test=# execute test('YYYY-MM-DD');
LOG:  statement: execute test('YYYY-MM-DD');
DETAIL:  prepare: prepare test as select to_char(current_date,$1);
LOG:  duration: 0.129 ms
  to_char
------------
 2019-12-14
(1 row)

test=#
```

Comment: Yes, I know what the `execute` format is, I was hoping I *wouldn't* have to transform the log output into the `execute` format.